# Prove $(aa^*bb^*)^*=ϵ+a(a+b)^*b$ using regex laws

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I tried to prove this by starting at RHS:

$$ϵ+a(a+b)^*b = ϵ+a(a^*b^*)^*b$$
But I dont know how to convert $(a^*b^*)^*$ to something else that will be helpful.
Any ideas?

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the body. Im assuming you made a writing mistake in the title

Comment: Or did you mean that this is what you tried to show, as a process of proving the question in the title?

Comment: @nirshahar Yes this was the process.

Answer (score 0):

We will not use regex equivalences, but rather show this directly by showing language equality:

First, we want to show that $L((aa^*bb^*)^*)\subseteq L(\epsilon + a(a+b)^*b)$: Take any word $w\in L((aa^*bb^*)^*)$. Its not hard to show that either $w=\epsilon$, or $w$ must start with $a$ and end with a $b$ (rewrite $bb^*$ as $b^*b$, it will help to prove this). Then, it will be clear that $w\in L(\epsilon+a(a+b)^*b)$.

Now we want to show that $L(\epsilon + a(a+b)^*b)\subseteq L((aa^*bb^*)^*)$: Take any word $w\in L(\epsilon + a(a+b)^*b)$. If $w=\epsilon$ its obvious why $w\in L((aa^*bb^*)^*)$. Otherwise, prove by induction over $|w|$ the length of $w$, that you can split $w$ in the following way:
$$w=x_1x_2,\dots,x_k$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_i \in L(aa^*b^*b)$.

Hint: define $x_1$ to be the substring of $w$ starting at the first element, and stopping at the first index $l$ such that $w_l=b$ but $w_{l+1}=a$. If there is no such index $l$, then take $x_1:=w$.

Comment: Oh sorry . Please delete this answer because I forgot to add epsilon on right side. I edited my question. Please make an answer for that if you can . Thanks again.

Comment: @program_craft Sure. Im not sure how regex equivalences will solve it, but if you are allowed to directly talk about the language of the regex then it might be possible.